# How can i write a special character: " to a file?

Tags: android

My problem is this character: `"`

```
String myLine = "<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">";
```

I want to write this line to a file, but this code does not work becouse of the `"` charaters inside the text i want to write. How can i change this character in the code to make it work but be displayable in the file?

Comment: You need to learn about escape characters.  You also need to use an XML library instead of building a string by hand.

Comment: You can escape `"` like this: `\"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the character with a \ so it would be \".

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 0):

You need to put escapes before the quotes with '\'s.

```
String myLine = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2\">";
```